# How to give access to kivy classes to take up parameters

Tags: python, class, kivy

Actually my doubt is that how can we provide parameters to a kivy class.. Example when we make a normal class in python we make a `__init__` function under which we provide some parameters `def __init__(self,x,y,z)` . How can we provide this type of parameters to a kivy class...
I have this class which I created in Kivy `my.kv file`

```
<MyGrid>:

    input : input
    label : label

    hint_text : self.hint_text
    pos_hint : self.pos_hint

    MDCard:
        size_hint : 0.75,0.44
        pos_hint :   self.pos_hint            #  This is first parameter
        elevation: 1

        FloatLayout:

            MDTextField:
                id : input
                markup: True
                multiline : True
                size_hint : 0.8,0.7
                pos_hint:{'x':0.05,'top':0.82}
                mode : 'rectangle'
                hint_text : self.hint_text # This is the second parameter
```

As u can see ,I have tried using `self.pos_hint` and `self.hint_text` but that doesn't work .I want to provide different pos and text for each MyGrid widget .. so any idea how can this be achieved or is their something which i am doing wrong.

```
#main .py file consist of just this class MyGrid

class MyGrid(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class by extending an existing `Widget` (the `FloatLayout` class is a `Widget`), then the `__init__()` of the super class will be called automatically. When you create an instance of `MyGrid`, the `__init__()` method of `FloatLayout` will be called. So you can define `MyGrid` like this:

```
class MyGrid(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

and you can specify properties of `MyGrid` just as you would for `FloatLayout`. For example, in your `kv`:

```
<MyGrid>:
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1.0}
```

So, in general, you can treat `MyGrid` exactly as you would `FloatLayout`.

And you can create your own properties in `MyGrid`, that can then be referenced in the 'kv'. Here is a modification of your posted code that does that:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp

kv = '''
<MyGrid>:
    input: input
    
    MDCard:
        size_hint : 0.75,0.44
        pos_hint : root.card_pos_hint            #  This is first parameter
        elevation: 1

        FloatLayout:

            MDTextField:
                id : input
                markup: True
                multiline : True
                size_hint : 0.8,0.7
                pos_hint:{'x':0.05,'top':0.82}
                mode : 'rectangle'
                hint_text : root.hint_text # This is the second parameter
'''

class MyGrid(FloatLayout):
    hint_text = StringProperty('')
    card_pos_hint = DictProperty()

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return MyGrid(hint_text='This is a Hint', card_pos_hint={'right':1, 'top':1})

TestApp().run()
```

Note that the `root` in the `kv` refers to `MyGrid`. Also, kivy automatically handles properties provided  in the `MyGrid()` creation as long as they are already defined in the `MyGrid` class. And, since `hint_text` and `card_pos_hint` are kivy `Properties`, the `MDTextField` hint will automatically update whenever you change the `hint_text` property of the `MyGrid` instance. Similarly, the position of the `MDCard` will automatically update whenever you modify the `card_pos_hint` property of the `MyGrid` instance.

Comment: Thnaks Brother but  how can i access the hint_text

Comment: It really worked as charm thanks was missing this stuff